# update query in linq to update the data in multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, linq, kendo-ui

I created kendo ui grid.I am able to load the data from the database.For this grid the data is coming from different tables ,I used joins in my linq query to load the data.
Now,I want to update the data using linq query,and update the data in different tables.
Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update individual records from each table and then execute db.SubmitChanges();

In your query the output is an anonymous type, not a table type connected to the dbContext.

If you think in terms of SQL, LinqToSql works very similar.
It´s possible to select a record set with a join, but you cannot update directly on this. You need to break it up and modify entries directly one by one.

Answer (score 0):

A DataContext instance tracks all the instances it loads.  When you call SubmitChanges, all of the changes are send to the database in one transaction.